# How to create wicket form with parameters

Tags: forms, wicket

default form in wicket looks like

```
private class TournamentWebForm extends Form<Void> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TournamentWebForm() {
        super("tournamentForm");
       // add componets ...
}
```

and then page looks like (important is number behind ?)

```
http://localhost:8080/tournament-system-web/home?19
```

but on the internet I found this page which is written in wicket too:

http://jizdenky.studentagency.cz/?wicket:interface=wicket-0:3:3:::

and when I search for ticket their form looks like:

http://jizdenky.studentagency.cz/Booking/from/BRNO/to/PRAHA/tarif/REGULAR/departure/20121213/retdep/20121213/return/false/ropen/false/credit/false/class/2.5#search-results

how I can create this form ?

UPDATE:

It look like that what page is return depends on last parameter in this case: `#search-results` how I can implement these feature ?

Answer (score 1):

You don 't.

What you see on the link above is the URL Wicket prior to version 1.5 created for statefull pages.

The secound URL is that of a BookmarkablePage with URL Parameters. See [mounting pages](http://wicketinaction.com/2011/07/wicket-1-5-mounting-pages/)

Follow the procedure in the link and pass the page parameters to your form via standard java options.

Comment: can you show me some example ? 1. there is form without "?number" I cant create this form but they have it. Second I cant image how they mount these page because there are over 10 parameter where can be a lot of possibilities = over 1 million combination.

Comment: third: I am not sure it they use mounting because I see this page alose: http://jizdenky.studentagency.cz/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=wicket-0:cz.sa.ybus.server.web.online.base.HomePage#search-results

Comment: The "?number" was introduced in 1.5. They use 1.4 or earlier. This is why you don't see it there.

Comment: @hudi you would end up with 10 page (url) parameters. That should not pose a problem. Actually 11 because wicket will add the page version number. But that is usually not a problem. And again: you don't mount forms, but pages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read about page parameters? You can find out something by visiting [Apache Wicket's home page](http://wicket.apache.org), and then following `Reference guide`, `Wicket reference`, `Pages`.

Enjoy?

Comment: sure I heard about it. Can you be more specific ? When I am using page parameters there is stil "?number"

Comment: The `?[Number]` is all about page instances, and Wicket keeping track of them. It's not a parameter for a Wicket page as such.